# Ignore file changes in TFS on configuration files

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

We have a couple of configuration files in our solution.  They are required for the software to function, so they need to be in our source control and pushed to new workspaces when the do a get latest for the first time.

The problem comes when the developers change these files to point to their local hard drive, database, etc. so they can develop and test.  Now TFS shows this as a pending change and developers have to be careful not to check these changes in to avoid messing up everyone's local config when they get latest.

I'd like it if there was a way to tell TFS to ignore changes on these files so we are not constantly having to exclude them from the changes we are checking in.  However, we need to make sure that whatever we do to make this work doesn't cause issues when pushing the code to a new workspace.  They'll still need to get the files the first time they do a get latest on a given branch.

Answer (score 0):

You could use .tfignore file to handle this situation.
 This file does not have any suffix. One way to create it suggest you to rename a new.txt file with `"tfignore."` It will auto change to right .tfignore file.

You can also use the **auto automatically generated .tfignore file**, follow below steps:

1. In the Pending Changes page, in the Excluded Changes section, choose
   the Detected changes link.

[image: pending changes, Detected changes link , which counts the number of adds, in this case 50003 add(s) (I have a busy directory clearly!)]

The Promote Candidate Changes dialog box appears.

2. Select a file, open its context menu, and choose Ignore this local
   item, Ignore by extension, Ignore by file name, or Ignore by folder.

[image: the promote candidate changes dialog opens. right-clicking an item in its list includes options like "Ignore by extension *.js"]

3. Choose OK or Cancel to close the Promote Candidate Changes dialog
           box.
4. A .tfignore file appears in the Included Changes section of the
       Pending Changes page. You can open this file and modify it to meet
      your needs.

[image: the .tfignore is automatically created by Visual Studio and appears in pending changes with the "add" notation, suggesting you will commit it]

More info please check the *Customize which files are ignored by version control* from MSDN Link:[Add files to the server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/add-files-server#customize-which-files-are-ignored-by-version-control)

---

With using `.tfignore` file, those configuration files changed in local will not list in TFS pending change and be auto excluded, however you could still pull down those files from server to local workspace.  Note this  `.tfignore` file will not affect with those files already in source control.  It it not work as a workaround you could deleted those configure files in source control and check in them again(force) after the .tfignore file generated.